# Actionscript 3.0 Resizing the parent without effecting the childrens

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the parent movieClip with multiple children in it.
How do i resize the parent without effecting the children movieClip?

Memo:The children must stay with the parent.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

/*The parents*/
var motherFather:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
motherFather.graphics.beginFill(0xAA0022);
motherFather.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
motherFather.width=100
motherFather.height=100
motherFather.x=10
motherFather.y=60

addChild(motherFather);
  for (var i:Number=1; i<=6;i++){
   var children:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
   children.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0260);
   children.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
   children.width=30
   children.height=30
   children.x=10 +(i*30)
   children.y=50
   motherFather.addChild(children);


  }
//CLICK ON STAGE TO RESIZE THE PARENT.
motherFather.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ResizeParent);
function ResizeParent(e:MouseEvent){
 motherFather.width+=150;

}
```

Comment: Make the fill as a child of motherFather as well.

Comment: What do you mean? I already had the    motherFather.addChild(children);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

/*The parents*/
var motherFather:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(motherFather);

var fill:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
fill.graphics.beginFill(0xAA0022);
fill.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
fill.width=100
fill.height=100
fill.x=10
fill.y=60

motherFather.addChild(fill);

  for (var i:Number=1; i<=6;i++){
   var children:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
   children.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0260);
   children.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
   children.width=30
   children.height=30
   children.x=10 +(i*30)
   children.y=50
   motherFather.addChild(children);

   addChild(new MovieClip());
  }
//CLICK ON STAGE TO RESIZE THE PARENT.
motherFather.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ResizeFill);
function ResizeFill(e:MouseEvent){
 fill.width+=150;
}
```

Something like that maybe?

Comment: the children are invisible now

Comment: did you copy the code till end? check if you have "}" in the end of the code. cause it works for me perfect!

Comment: Why are you adding a bunch of empty MovieClips with `addChild(new MovieClip());`? Does that actually do something?

Answer (score 0):

More or less similar to Richards' answer, except for the transparency...

You can simply add a transparent background to your motherFather MovieClip and resize that instead of resizing the motherFather MovieClip itself.

```
var background:Shape = new Shape();
background.name = "background";

background.graphics.beginFill( 0 , 0 );
//add the rest of the graphics functions

motherFather.addChild(background );

function resize(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    motherFather.getChildByName("background").with += 150;
}
```

Also, if you're only going to create shapes, there's no need to use MovieClips , use Shape instances for the children and a Sprite for the container.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I still like to stick with the movieClip because it offers more options, the performance is not that bad. The transparency idea is good. Thanks